# GCP load balancer to point to index.html in /bucket/folder1/folder2/index.html

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, load-balancing

I have a bucket `bucketName` and couple of folders inside it (`folder1/folder2/`..

`Folder2` is index.html file, `js/*` and `css/*` folders. I would like to create a domain mapping using GCP load balancer (domain.com) to point to LB IP.

I have already tried with Advanced settings in *host and path rule* but not working. Can someone guide me.

Comment: Try this `gsutil web set -m folder1/folder2/index.html gs://bucketName`. Not sure that works... Let me know

Comment: It seems that the intention is to use load balancer instead of just the static hosting?  Can you add why?

Comment: The intention of adding LB is that I wanted to have multiple domain hosted on single buckets at different folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by below structure:

1. created a LB.
2. In the path mapping section, go to advanced settings and click on host and path rewite.
3. In the path rewrite, define the folder path.

You may have to wait for some time to get it reflected.